How to get the correct 3D rotation matrix given two vectors?
Context:
Imagine there is a coordinate axes and a normalized vector, v1 from its origin. Now, suppose the coordinate axes rotates only by yawing a certain angle, $\phi$. After this rotation, the vector v1 becomes v2.
After research, I found out that I can find the yaw, pitch and roll angles of the rotation solely from v1 and v2 by first finding the axis-angle representation and then converting it to a ,e.g, ZYX rotation matrix. From this rotation matrix, the Euler angles (yaw, pitch and roll) can be found. Also, I understand that only one combination for a sequence of angles exists for a given rotation. For example, there is only one ZYX matrix to rotate v1 to v2.
Problem:
I am still confused with this methodology and in general determining Euler angles from two vectors. Here is an example:
$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}0.577 \\ 0.577 \\ 0.577 \end{bmatrix}$
Using a simulation, I added $v_1$ to a scene with a coordinate axes. I only yawed the coordinate axes by $35^{\circ}$ giving a relatively rotated vector, $v_2$. You can see this since the z component of both vectors remains unchanged.
$v_2=\begin{bmatrix}0.804 \\ 0.142 \\ 0.577 \end{bmatrix}$
Then, in MATLAB, I used the code below to determine the Euler angles which should be:
Yaw: $35^{\circ}$,
Pitch: $0^{\circ}$,
Roll: $0^{\circ}$
The MATLAB angles are not what I expect them to be. What is strange is that the rotation matrix found in MATLAB still rotates the vector $v_1$ to $v_2$. This finally brings me to the question: How can I find the Euler angles which correctly shows the yaw, pitch and roll taken from $v_1$ to $v_2$?

MATLAB Code:
v1 = [0.5773502691896257; 0.5773502691896257; 0.5773502691896257];
v2 = [0.803969186042821; 0.1424788214448403; 0.5773502691896257];
c = cross(v1, v2);
a = c / norm(c);

angle = acos(dot(v1, v2));

axang = [a(1) a(2) a(3) angle];
rotm = axang2rotm(axang);

disp("v1:");
disp(v1);
disp("v2:");
disp(v2);

disp("Rotation matrix:");
disp(rotm);

disp("Apply rotation matrix to v1 to get v2:");
disp(rotm * v1);

eul = rotm2eul(rotm, "ZYX") * 180 / pi


MATLAB Output:
v1:
    0.5774
    0.5774
    0.5774

v2:
    0.8040
    0.1425
    0.5774

Rotation matrix:
    0.9133    0.3994    0.0798
   -0.3644    0.8889   -0.2777
   -0.1818    0.2245    0.9574

Apply rotation matrix to v1 to get v2:
    0.8040
    0.1425
    0.5774


eul =

  -21.7536   10.4775   13.1968


“Also, I understand that only one combination for a sequence of angles exists for a given rotation.” Why do you think this? It is an incorrect understanding. There are many rotations that will take $v_1$ to $v_2$. You used one to find coordinates of $v_2$. MATLAB computed another. Do you know what each step of the MATLAB script does and why? For example, why is there a cross product? What is the purpose of axang? What does axang2rotm do, and how would that be useful?

Yes, you're right, I'm sorry. I misread this from another answer. The cross product is there to determine the axis of rotation. Thank you for your help.

Why is the axis of rotation a cross product of these two vectors? You already had an axis of rotation; does the cross product tell you what that axis was?

I didn't have an axis of rotation before. That is why I found the cross product. The cross product of two vectors gives the direction of the vector perpendicular to both. So, rotating $v_1$ around this vector by the angle (found by dot product of $v_1$ and $v_2$) will get $v_2$. I'm not sure if you're helping me now or just quizzing me. Though, your initial comment was helpful. Thank you.

Yaw is a rotation about the vertical axis. The only way you could get yaw $35^\circ$ and zero for the other two Euler angles would be by finding an axis-angle representation with a vertical axis. But the two vectors are not perpendicular to the vertical axis, so the cross product gives you a different axis.

And yes, I may have come on a bit strong with the Socratic method.

That makes sense. So if I set the axis to be the vertical axis, I could then get the yaw. Thanks for your help! And no worries.

If you’re curious, somewhere on this site there was a question about rotating one vector to another where someone worked out in an answer what all the possible axes of rotation are and how they relate to the angle of rotation. Sadly I’ve had no luck finding the question.
